# Set Properties of linq object to those of another

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have a complex object / entity pulled from the database which has 50-60 fields. I've generated a form for this by hand and it was a pain in the bum. I don't want to have to now write c# code to manually apply each property.

I thought I could do this

```
using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
    var _contact = db.Contact.Where(x => x.ID == model.Contact.ID).FirstOrDefault();
    _contact = model.Contact;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, this does not update the object. I guess the reference to the original is lost when I set `_contact = model.Contact`

I've found a lot of similar threads on SO with this solution (or variations):

```
var notNullProps = typeof(Contact).GetProperties()
                   .Where(x => x.GetValue(model.Contact, null) != null);
foreach (var p in notNullProps)
{
    p.SetValue(_contact, p.GetValue(model.ContactWithMetaData.Contact, null), null);
}
```

However this always throws the error `Non-static method requires a target`

I've even tried using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), even though my objects are of the same class. It seemed to lose the reference to the object too. It's late and I may be doing something stupid. Can anyone help?

**UPDATE:**

My AutoMapper Code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, Contact>();
Mapper.Map(model.ContactWithMetaData.Contact, _contact);
db.SaveChanges();
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Sorry folks. It turns out I *was* doing something stupid. I was populating my form with `model.Contact` but had omitted a hidden field for `Contact.ID`. As a result `Contact.ID` and `_contact` were both null to begin with. Now that I've seen my mistake, I've gone back and tested. Both methods above work, and wahwahwah's method also works.

Sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Comment: Automapper should be the thing you need, and it should work fine even when the instances being mapped are the same type. Can you show that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help:

```
public void SetProperties(object source, object target)
{
    var contactType = target.GetType();
    foreach (var prop in source.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var propGetter = prop.GetGetMethod();
        var propSetter = contactType.GetProperty(prop.Name).GetSetMethod();
        var valueToSet = propGetter.Invoke(source, null);
        propSetter.Invoke(target, new[] { valueToSet });
    }
}
```

Only works if the properties of both objects are exactly the same (case sensitive.) Not as robust as AutoMapper...

Comment: is there a typo in this? `contactType` is unrecognised? guessing it should be `type`?

Answer (score 0):

By doing `_contact = model.Contact;` you are replacing the entire reference of `_contact` with the reference to `model.Contact`. The original object referred to by `_contact` is unchanged and hence there is nothing to save.

Comment: yes, I guessed that. So how to I apply the properties from one to the other without going through every single one?

Comment: Personally I would use reflection to get the names of the properties and then codegen the property assignments and then paste them in to your code. "wahwahwah" has a suitable method, but I never like seeing something like this in code as it can lead to subtle bugs later on.